# GWT in eclipse javax.jws.WebMethod is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I created a GWT application in eclipse using the GWT eclipse plugin. By default it created GreetingServiceAsync.java and GreetingService.java in client package. GreetingServiceImpl.java in server package.

Now I want to call a CXF webservice from GreetingServiceImpl.java. I used wsdl2java to generate java classes for my wsdl. I imported these generated class in my GWT project in eclipse and the package is "service". But it complains "javax.jws.WebMethod is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment", many more errors.

How do I get rid of this?

Only error is the problem otherwise application is running fine.

Answer (score 1):

Is `javax.jws.WebMethod` in the GAE [whitelist](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html)?  If you're sure that this class is really supported in the App Engine, then in Eclipse try:

- Right click your project in the Project Explorer.
- `Google -> App Engine Settings`
- Make sure **Use Google App Engine** is checked
- Try changing the App Engine SDK to the latest rev, if the dialog shows multiple ones

I had this problem after doing Software Update; a new GAE SDK was installed and for some reason it confused the plugin.  It was telling me that `java.lang.String` was unsupported. :-)

Comment: No its not there in whitelist that is why its giving that problem. But I want it to compile properly in eclipse.

Comment: Are you not actually using Google App Engine?  If you're only interested in GWT, but not App Engine, make suer that Using Google App Engine is NOT checked.